# how to make a calculator but have more than 2 inputs?

Tags: javascript, calculator

here is a link to what im basing my code off of....but i want there to be more than 2 areas to type numbers in if that makes sense...so number 1, number 2, then number 3...etc

[LINK](http://kalyan-city.blogspot.com/2009/11/simple-javascript-calculator-code.html)

Ive tried to copy everything down but then adding

```
c=Number(document.calculator.number3.value); 
d=Number(document.calculator.number4.value);

<!-- Here user will enter 3rd number. -->   
Number 3: <input type="text" name="number3">  
<!-- Here user will enter 4th number. -->   
Number 4: <input type="text" name="number4">
```

and changing the result to e=a+b+c+d
but then the calculator stops functioning

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show all your related code and html.  Are there any javascript errors?

Comment: Did you change from `document.calculator.total.value=c;` to `document.calculator.total.value=e;`?

Comment: P.S. i only want to do addition

Comment: You should check your code, because everything should work... No matter what action to modify: only addition or all others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try - http://jsfiddle.net/GmDuE/

HTML

```
Number 1: <input type="text" name="number1">
Number 2: <input type="text" name="number2">
Number 3: <input type="text" name="number3">
Number 4: <input type="text" name="number4">
```

JS

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function multiply(){
a=Number(document.calculator.number1.value);
b=Number(document.calculator.number2.value);
c=Number(document.calculator.number3.value);
d=Number(document.calculator.number4.value);
m=a*b*c*d;
document.calculator.total.value=m;
}

function addition(){
a=Number(document.calculator.number1.value);
b=Number(document.calculator.number2.value);
c=Number(document.calculator.number3.value);
d=Number(document.calculator.number4.value);
m=a+b+c+d;
document.calculator.total.value=m;
}
</script>

etc.
```

Comment: ok that works...but now for a harder question....can i make it so that the calculator takes into consideration already known numbers (within the code)

Comment: can you edit the jsfiddle to show what do you mean by `already known numbers`?

Comment: nope, the spaces don't matter. I removed a colon `:` from the total input name - it was `total:` :) And you are welcome!

Comment: @ZoltanToth—so others get senseless drive-by down votes too! ;-)

Comment: @RobG Looks like some people just feel the irresistible urge for being a$$holes. The necessary evil at SO :)